# Lenovo laptop re-load of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad

My son has a Lenovo Thinkpad and the screen is broken.  He uses an external monitor to use the computer.  We've had to re-load Windows 7, but after a while, the screen goes black and we get nothing on the external monitor to see how far the disc has loaded.  We've tried taking out the battery and switching it on again and still nothing.  Please help because I really need to sort this out as we can't afford another laptop or computer.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bad cable. Have you tried switching cables? It could also be an internal hardware problem on the laptop.

Comment: It was working fine yesterday. My son wanted to re-load windows because he is a gamer and there was a problem with some of the online games. We've taken the cable out and plugged it in again. But have an extra one will try that as well! Thanks

Comment: We seem to think that it has something to do with the external monitor and internal display.  The cable is fine as it was working a little earlier today and the laptop came on when we started the re-load of windows disc.

Comment: Does the laptop still run with the black screen? If so, then it could be that the display hardware is damaged.

Comment: Also, it could be the video card driver that was installed with the re-load of Windows.